# Can I find out why a MongoDB query had no matches?

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I often use `findOneAndUpdate` to get and update documents based on multiple conditions, for example:

```js
const { value } = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "abc", name: "xyz" },
  { $set: { ... } }
);
```

If there is no document that matched the query, I would like to know *why* the match failed so that I can return useful error messages to users. For example, if no document with `_id == "abc"` exists, I would like to return a message like "Document not found." If it does exist but has a different `name`, the message should be "Name is incorrect." At the moment, I can only find out if the *entire* query matched by checking the returned `value`.

I could, of course, call `findOne({ _id: "abc" })`, check if `name` has the correct value, and call `updateOne` afterwards but I would prefer one atomic operation.

Is there a way to do this or do I have to use a transaction in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As per the implementation notes, `findOneAndUpdate()` returns `Collection~findAndModifyCallback` i.e. the collection result callback. This callback internally has two fields

- error (An error instance representing the error during the execution.)
- result (The result object if the command was executed successfully.)

This result object, internally holds 3 values,

- value (Document returned from findAndModify command.)
- lastErrorObject (The raw lastErrorObject returned from the command.)
- ok (Is 1 if the command executed correctly.)

You can probably use these values to do the stuff you exactly want.

Links

- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate
- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~findAndModifyCallback
- https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~findAndModifyWriteOpResult

Comment: Thanks for answering but the returned values don't seem to provide the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the update operation and if the returned value is `null` (no match found) - send a message to the application user.

The `findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback)` has the `findAndModifyCallback(error, result)` and the `result` value will be `null` if the update query didn't match. See note below on the `findOneAndUpdate` option `returnOriginal`:

The option `returnOriginal` is boolean `true` by default. If no documents were found, value will be `null` by default (returnOriginal: true), even if a document was upserted; when `false`, returns the updated document rather than the original. *Set this as false*, and in case you are using the upsert option, so that the value will be `null` in case there is no match.

So, if the result value is `null`, this means the query didn't match and the update didn't happen and you can return an appropriate message. How? You still have to run a `find` query, and:

```
if (id not found)
    send message "Document not found."
else // name not found
    send message "Name is incorrect."
```

If you don't want to run a `find` query again, just send a *generic* message to the application user.

*Transactions?*

If your deployment is a replica-set or sharded cluster then [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) is a possibility. Note transactions are available only with the latest MongoDB versions (4.0 for replica-sets and 4.2 for sharded clusters).